# import pandas library results in error: ImportError: cannot import name Counter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataFrame in python and the only way I have found so far is to use the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
newfilename = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

However, when I try to excute this code, I am getting an error which says:

> ImportError: cannot import name Counter

I googled and found that in python 2.6 and older versions, this error is common and they said I should install backport_collections : 0.1 to solve this issue like is explained in the below page:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backport_collections/0.1

However, I have no experience in doing it in the unix virtual machine.
It seems that I have to download the package "backport_collections-0.1.tar.gz" and after that I dont know how to install it or in which directory to install it. 
After installation I need to import counter as follows:

from backport_collections import Counter

Please advise me on how to install this package "backport_collections-0.1.tar.gz" as I am completely new to python.

Comment: Use a virtualenv and install backport_collections to that?

Comment: There are two entirely unconnected questions here, one a simple dataframe question and another an installation one.  Aside: you should *strongly* consider upgrading to modern Python (3.5), or at least 2.7.  2.6 final came out in 2008 and is no longer supported by modern pandas, so you could be in for all sorts of other headaches a beginner might not know to watch out for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I cannot upgrade to newer version because the program I am writing is part of an old program written in python 2.6.